# CouchDB Access Denied Redirect

Tags: security, authentication, redirect, couchdb, access-denied

When I punch in the URL for a secured database it displays the following message on the page:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not authorized to access this db."}
```

Although this message certainly gets the point across I would prefer to redirect the user to a different page, like a login page. I've tried changing the authentication_redirect option in the couch config but no success. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication redirect is only works if client explicitly accepts `text/html` content type (e.g. sends `Accept: text/html` header):

```
GET /db HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html
Host: localhost:5984
```

In this case, CouchDB will send `HTTP 302` response instead of `HTTP 401` which redirects on your authentication form, specified with `authentication_redirect` configuration option:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Length: 78
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 01:32:40 GMT
Location: http://localhost:5984/_utils/session.html?return=%2Fdb&reason=You%20are%20not%20authorized%20to%20access%20this%20db.
Server: CouchDB/1.4.0 (Erlang OTP/R16B01)

{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not authorized to access this db."}
```

Othewise CouchDB doesn't know was request send by human from browser or by application library. In the last case redirecting to the HTML form instead of raising HTTP error isn't suitable solution.

Comment: ok, but is there a solution, using something else? Is there a way to make this message human readable? That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: This message is only shown before browser makes the redirect. The end user will see the page at URL from the `Location` header that may and should be human readable (:

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! I get this message when I visit a vhost that takes me to a rewrite for a particular database. I think I have to tweak my settings a bit to get it working how I want. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `curl -v -H "Accept: text/html" http://localhost:5984/db/_design/design/_rewrite` gives me the nice `302` like in this answer. However in a web browser, I get `401`. Do you know how I can fix this?